# How do I output data between two dates in bash?

Tags: bash, perl, loops, logfile

I have a file like this:

```
2014-12-31 531.252429 532.602384 525.802363 526.402397 1368200 526.402397
2014-12-30 528.092396 531.152424 527.132366 530.422394 876300 530.422394
2014-12-29 532.192446 535.482414 530.013375 530.332426 2278500 530.332426
2014-12-26 528.772422 534.252417 527.312364 534.032454 1036000 534.032454
2014-12-24 530.512424 531.761394 527.022384 528.772422 705900 528.772422
2014-12-23 527.00237 534.56241 526.292354 530.592416 2197600 530.592416
```

and want to echo each line between 2014-12-31 and 2014-12-23 in a bash script.

I tried this before, but it ended up showing me the lines I wanted but in a never-ending loop.

```
perl -ne 'if ( m/^([0-9-]+)/ ) { $date = $1; print if ( $date ge "2014-12-31" and $date le "2014-12-23" ) }' file.txt
```

What went wrong and how can I fix the code?

Comment: Are they dates sorted in reverse order like that?

Answer (score 2):

If the lines are sorted by date, you could simply use the Perl's `..` [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

```
perl -ne 'print if /2014-12-31/ .. /2014-12-23/' file.txt
```

To fix your one-liner, swap the `le` and `ge` operators to set the range correctly:

```
perl -ne 'if ( m/^([0-9-]+)/ ) { $date = $1; print if ( $date le "2014-12-31" and $date ge "2014-12-23" ) }' file.txt
```

Comment: Tried this, it prints the lines over and over (like in a loop) too. What could be causing this?

Comment: Your first solution doesn't work if there's 0 records with the later date, if there's 0 records with the earlier date, or if there are 2+ records with the earlier date.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the records with dates *before* your start date and *after* your end date.
You should be printing the records with dates *after* your start date and *before* your end date.
To fix, just flip the dates around:

```
perl -ne'if ( m/^([0-9-]+)/ ) { $date = $1; print if ( $date ge "2014-12-23" and $date le "2014-12-31" ) }'
```

Shorter version:

```
perl -ane'print if $F[0] ge "2014-12-23" && $F[0] le "2014-12-31"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to say - I'd probably tackle it by parsing the time and date stamps into epoch times, then comparing those.

So something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
my $end = Time::Piece->strptime( "2014-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d" );
my $start = Time::Piece->strptime( "2014-12-23", "%Y-%m-%d" );

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( (split)[0], "%Y-%m-%d" );
    print if $t > $start and $t < $end;
}

__DATA__
2014-12-31 531.252429 532.602384 525.802363 526.402397 1368200 526.402397
2014-12-30 528.092396 531.152424 527.132366 530.422394 876300 530.422394
2014-12-29 532.192446 535.482414 530.013375 530.332426 2278500 530.332426
2014-12-26 528.772422 534.252417 527.312364 534.032454 1036000 534.032454
2014-12-24 530.512424 531.761394 527.022384 528.772422 705900 528.772422
2014-12-23 527.00237 534.56241 526.292354 530.592416 2197600 530.592416
```

It's converting your date stamp into an epoch (second since 1970) as you would get from `time()`.

You could probably collapse this down to a one liner:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -ane 'BEGIN{@R=map { Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%Y-%m-%d") } qw ( 2014-12-23 2014-12-31 )} $t = Time::Piece->strptime($F[0],"%Y-%m-%d"); print if $t > $R[0] and $t < $R[1]'
```

Now, I know that's a bit heavyweight for your use case, but the advantage of doing this is that it can quite easily support different date formats.

Comment: What a waste! String comparisons are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since your dates are ISO 8601, you can compare lexicographically.

You do not need a regex; just use awk like auto split.

Given:

```
$ echo "$dates"
2014-12-31 531.252429 532.602384 525.802363 526.402397 1368200 526.402397
2014-12-30 528.092396 531.152424 527.132366 530.422394 876300 530.422394
2014-12-29 532.192446 535.482414 530.013375 530.332426 2278500 530.332426
2014-12-26 528.772422 534.252417 527.312364 534.032454 1036000 534.032454
2014-12-24 530.512424 531.761394 527.022384 528.772422 705900 528.772422
2014-12-23 527.00237 534.56241 526.292354 530.592416 2197600 530.592416
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$dates" | perl -lane 'print if $F[0] gt "2014-12-28" && $F[0] lt "2014-12-31"'
2014-12-30 528.092396 531.152424 527.132366 530.422394 876300 530.422394
2014-12-29 532.192446 535.482414 530.013375 530.332426 2278500 530.332426
```